# grub does not show Windows 8 installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have a triple boot Ubuntu14.10/MacOSX/Windows 8 on my MacBook Pro.

However, Windows does not show up in grub, only MacOS and Ubuntu show up.

I tried a few things from other similar questions but nothing worked, like running `update-grub` or `Boot Repair`. Here are some program outputs which might be helpful:

### fdisk

```
sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2f014951

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1      409639      204819+  ee  GPT
/dev/sda2          409640    49237767    24414064   af  HFS / HFS+
/dev/sda3        49500160   322936831   136718336    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4   *   322936832   500117503    88590336   83  Linux
```

I guess /dev/sda3 might be windows !?

### update-grub

```
sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
Found Mac OS X on /dev/sda2
done
```

### os-prober

```
sudo os-prober
/dev/sda2:Mac OS X:MacOSX:macosx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the repository and hope this will help you to use the GRUB in windows 8. Please try the below commands,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair &&

sudo apt-get update &&

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair &&

boot-repair
```

Comment: Tried this already; didn't help